# Why is RSA easily cracked if N is prime?

Tags: rsa

This question was part of an assignment.
Here's my reasonning:

- If N is prime and N=p*q, then p=1 and q=N (or the opposite).
- e * d ≡ 1 mod ((p-1) * (q-1)), but ((p-1) * (q-1))=0 here.
- e * d ≡ 1 mod 0, so e=d.
- We now have the private key.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is worth noting that as ''1'' isn't a prime, when p=1 it isn't RSA anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this correct?

**Sadly no.**

First here's a simple counter-example: $n=11,e=3\Rightarrow d=7\neq 3$, also note that $(5^3)^3\equiv 9\not\equiv 5\pmod {11}$ and $(5^3)^7\equiv 5\pmod {11}$.

Concretely the mistake in the calculations is finding the order for exponent (e.g. the totient function of the modulus), which the calculations hard-code to $\varphi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$ which is only true for $p,q\in\mathbb P$.
The fix is to use the proper formula which obviously is $\varphi(1\cdot q)=q-1$. Now you can proceed normally in calculating $d$ as solution to $e\cdot d\equiv 1\pmod{q-1}$.

Comment: How do I calculate d? My first instinct would be to state that e.d = q...

Comment: @OlivierGrech you calculate $d$ as you would with standard RSA, e.g. as $d=e^{-1}\bmod{(q-1)}$.

Comment: $e^{-1}$ denotes the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), usually computed with the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

The totient $\phi$ of a prime number $N$ is trivial to calculate as all integers less than $N$ are co-prime with $N$, hence $\phi(N) = N-1$. Once we know $\phi(N) = N-1$ we can easily recover the private key $d$ from the public key $(e, N)$, we just calculate $d = e^{-1} \text{ mod } (N-1)$.